# Longest Consecutive Runs of "A"

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to identify the problem with a "corner case" for my code.  Basically, I am trying to find the longest consecutive run of "A" in an inputted string.  I have a solution, but it's not ideal - see the condition at the bottom.  Basically, how can I set `max` to 4 if the string is just "AAAA" and just print that out?

```
dna = input()
index = 0
length = len(dna)
counter = 0
max = 0

while index < length:
    if dna[index] == 'A':
        counter += 1
    else:
        if counter > max:
            max = counter
        counter = 0
    index += 1

if 'A' * length == dna:
    print(length)
else:
    print(max)
```

Comment: I may be misunderstanding your corner case. It seems to me your code outputs the correct number of `A`'s. What does the `if` construction at the end add? It only says "if the input is *all* `A`s, output the length of that input" – but you don't *need* that extra check because the regular counting code already works correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is also going to have issues for any string with the longest run of 'A's at the very end of the string for the same reason.

Basically you should assign your max value after every check and not just after finding the next non-match

```
while index < length:
    if dna[index] == 'A':
        counter += 1
    else:
        counter = 0
    if counter > max:
        max = counter
    index += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a "recursive" solution here. 
To solve the problem of which the string is just "AAAAA", at the end of the loop/recursion, if counter > max value, the function will return counter instead of max value.

```
def find_longest_A(dna, counter = 0, max = 0):
    ''' counter: the current consecutive length of A
        max : Max value of A consecutive run'''
    if len(dna) == 0:
        if (counter > max):
            return counter
        return max
    if dna[0] == "A":
        counter += 1
    else:
        if (counter > max):
            max = counter
        counter = 0
    return find_longest_A(dna[1:],counter, max)
```